# My living room outlets are not working after installing new ceiling fan and switch. Ceiling fan and included light works fine

Tags: switch, receptacle

[image][image][image]enter image description hereSo I installed a new ceiling fan and included switch now my living room outlets dont work. Fan and ceiling fan light work fine.

https://www.wayfair.com/lighting/pdp/mercury-row-52-mcnemar-3-blade-led-propeller-ceiling-fan-and-light-kit-included-w002792210.html

There are 3 wire bundles in the switch box... 1 going to fan (fan works), 1 to bathroom switch box, 1 to I have no idea where.

I checked all the following:

- Red to blue (fan light)
- Black white stripe (AC in on switch) to other two black wires.
- Black (to motor) on switch to other single black wire labeled motor.
- Whites all tie together
- Grounds all together.

Just want to make sure I didnt miss something obvious before I call an electrician! Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide  pictures of the ceiling box and the switch box?

Comment: Ceiling box? You mean where the fan is hung? There’s only one bundle going to fan and it works fine and it’s super heavy so don’t want to remove it unless absolutely necessary. For the attic it’s just wires and they run straight to the switch box in the wall. Unfortunately I haven’t been able to fish the other cable down the wall so now it’s just wires sticking out.

Comment: Not sure how to add pics from my phone app. Not sure what pics I could take in the attic as its just one bundle from light down wall, one bundle up from bathroom switch back down into hole next to it in same wall, and one bundle going I dont know where to rest of house, other end down wall that I cant fish out yet. :)

Comment: Could it be that you have failed to reconnect the feed to the cable going to the wall receptacles? Or is there is a GFCI receptacle somewhere that needs to be reset?  Was there previously a wall switch where you have the switch/controller for the fan? If not, where did you tap in to get feed: in the attic or in the wall? You have done a lot of work on this and I you should try hard to figure it out without calling an electrician.

Comment: Hi Jim, there was previously two wall switches there and I replaced with the combo fan switch provides. I have all three wire bundles connected, two of which I know where they go. Other I can just assume is the outlet feed but how would I tell? Do I just have the trace the wire through the attic or is there a more sophisticated way?

Comment: We need to know what the wiring was like before you started. The receptacles definitely worked before you started, right?

Comment: Yes, it was just two switches in the wall to old ceiling fan. Not sure you can tell anything from pic I took previously. Doesn’t look like I can upload from phone so have to be when I get home.

Comment: Do you have a VOM? Into one of the non working receptacles plug an extension cord long enough to reach the ends of the two cables which are a mystery. Check continuity (meaning ~zero resistance, i.e., zero ohms) between neutrals. If testing the hots, be sure none is hot or you'll damage the meter. EDIT Disconnect the wires of the unknown cables to test them.

Comment: You mentioned a bathroom switch box.  You have to check for power there too. Is this for a light? Does this light work now?

Comment: Yes the lights at the bathroom switch which is the hot that feeds the fan and other one works fine as does the fan and fan light. Very odd.

Comment: I have one more but it won’t let me edit it anymore.

Comment: I do have a vom that’s a good idea thank you.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you for all the help on this. We decided to have can lights put in and the electrician fixed this at the same time. I still don’t understand what I did wrong, something about the feed, I didn’t understand lol. 

Thank you